# Is it possible to connect a slave device with SSI to master with I2C/SPI?

Tags: i2c, ssi

I have a National Instruments USB-8451 controller that needs to work with an AMO encoder. The NI controller supports I2C and SPI. The encoder supports EnDat, Fanuc, SSI, and TTL. I believe that logically, I2C and SSI may be compatible.

Is my assumption correct? Is it possible to connect the two devices?

Thanks!

[AMO encoder data sheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xYiG4AmPhRVFXBgdmBLPoj9e7D57BcgJ/view?usp=sharing)
[USB-8421 data sheet](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/290598a.pdf)

Comment: Do you have a link to AMO encoder datasheet?

Comment: I had added a link.

Comment: I²C is far from SSI. Perhaps you need to read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_Serial_Interface

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was solved with a custom physical adapter.